# Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable in UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following code snippet:

```
struct player : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    var url : String
    var player1: AVPlayer
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<player>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        player1 = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: url)!)
        controller.player = player1
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<player>) {
    }
    
    func pause() {
        player1.pause()
    }
}
```

This gives the error:

> 'Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable'

I need to have the AVPlayer outside of the makeUIViewController function because I need to access it from the pause function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are seeing appears due to the fact that structs are value types and any method on them that changes their properties needs to be marked as `mutating`. Unfortunately you cannot mark `makeUIViewController` because it is defined in `UIViewControllerRepresentable` protocol, but there is a fairly easy solution.

You only actually use the url to construct an `AVPlayer` - there is no need to hold on to it. Write and initializer for your struct that takes a url string and constructs an `AVPlayer`. I have made the `AVPlayer` optional as `URL(string: String)` returns an `Optional URL` (as you can imagine not all strings are valid urls). The below code works as expected:

```
struct Player: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var player1: AVPlayer?

    public init(url string: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: string) else {
            self.player1 = nil
            return
        }
        self.player1 = AVPlayer(url: url)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Player>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player1
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Player>) {}

    func pause() {
        player1?.pause()
    }
}
```

A side note: all type names in Swift (classes, structs, enums) are by convention upper-cased: your struct should be called `Player` not `player`.
You should also look into `Cordinator` for `UIViewControllerRepresentable` - you need something to act as your `AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities to choose from (actually it is not a complete list of options, but hope it would be helpful)

**Option1:** Do it in initailizer

```
struct player : UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    private var url : String
    private var player1: AVPlayer

    init(url: String) {
        self.url = url
        self.player1 = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: url)!)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<player>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player1
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<player>) {
    }
}
```

**Option2:** Do it on first request to update controller

```
struct player : UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var url : String
    var player1: AVPlayer

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<player>) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        return AVPlayerViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ playerController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<player>) {
        if playerController.player == nil {
            playerController.player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: url)!)
        }
    }
}
```

**Option3:** If you need to modify `player1` during lifetime, then you need to keep it in some external entity, say ObservableObject, because your `player` is View struct and cannot modify itself, actually what is said in compiler error.